# Swift 4 Decodable, DecodingError : No value associated with key

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4, codable

I'm trying to use the Swift 4 Codable feature but got stuck in this situation:

```
struct Message:Codable {

let message: String
let timestamp: String
let latitude: String
let longitude: String}
```

This is my struct.

```
guard let url = URL(string:"http://localhost:443/api/message") else {return}
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    print("POSTED")

    let newPost = Message(message: "Hi", timestamp: "1", latitude: "1.1", longitude: "2.2")

    print("NewPost:",newPost)

    do {
        let jsonBody = try JSONEncoder().encode(newPost)
        request.httpBody = jsonBody

    } catch let err  {
        print("jsonBody Error: ",err)
    }

    let session = URLSession.shared
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request){ (data,response,err) in
        guard let data = data else {return}
        do{
            let sendPost = try JSONDecoder().decode(Message.self, from: data)
            print("sendPost:\(sendPost)")
        }catch let err{
            print("Session Error: ",err)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

And this is the function I use for post request.
In the print("NewPost:",newPost), it prints

```
NewPost: Message(message: "Hi", timestamp: "1", latitude: "1.1", longitude: "2.2")
```

which looked very identical to other examples I saw,
but then there's always a Session Error by catch

```
Session Error:  keyNotFound(DeadDrop.Message.(CodingKeys in _5C64F74710315F52702B56CE54E28C19).message, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key message (\"message\").", underlyingError: nil))
```

I just don't understand how this came up! I'm using the exact same struct and it says there's no key for this?!
Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you post what is your `data` printing?

Comment: It has to do with how Message object is encoded. Can you post the code for the Message class?

Comment: If I use print("DATA:\(data)") after the print("Session Error: ",err), it prints "DATA:68 bytes" ... how can I see what's inside? @ViniApp

Comment: The Message struct is at the top! There's no Message class. @NSAdi

Comment: My bad. Could you print jsonBody?

Comment: use like this `let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) print("JSON String : ", jsonString!)`

Comment: It showes `DATA:{"code":"ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE","errno":1292,"sqlState":"#22007"}` @ViniApp

Comment: I think your data is wrong. From server side they are sending some error.

Comment: May be you are sending some values in wrong format in 'Message`.

Comment: So does this mean the decoding works fine, but the server doesn't accept my format? @ViniApp

Comment: Yes decoding is working fine, may be in server they are expecting different datatypes. Please confirm with them.

Comment: No prob! It looked like this `{"message":"Hi","timestamp":"1","latitude":"1.1","longitude":"2.2"}` @NSAdi

Comment: THANKS!! That's all I need to know!! Would you mind to put this to the answer so I can pick you as the right answer? @ViniApp

Comment: Please check my answer. Change your timestamp value to "1508309342".

Comment: I suspect `1` is not a valid timestamp right, thats why its throwing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **SQLState: 22007** :
>   The string representation of a datetime is not in the acceptable range or is not in the correct format.

As you told that you are getting `data` as below :

```
{"code":"ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE","errno":1292,"sqlSta‌​te":"#22007"}
```

As per this [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_11.0.0/codes/src/tpc/n180.html), It is expecting different datatype than you are sending.

I suspect the `timestamp` you are sending is `1`, and this is not a valid `timestamp`.

Try to send `timestamp` value as "1508309342"

Other than that your decoding code is fine.

Comment: Thanks! I actually have the format of Time Stamp (`timestamp: 2017-09-10 10:22:33`), but I thought this error is caused by JSON not be able to decode. So knowing it's error from the server really helped!

Comment: Oh wait, sorry but I just noticed that it was showing `"No value associated with key message (\"message\")."` so why is it not accepting my message rather than the timestamp? The message has no limit other than <280 character String.